# Scheduler using Timer Queues

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I am working on an application where i need to schedule tasks based on the time set by the user. The user may add/modify/delete the schedules. To implement it i am considering using Timer Queues. Initially i though of using WaitableTimers which suite very much for my purpose but i cant make my thread to sleep for competing the APC.

Now with the Timer Queue i am not sure how to set the timer to signal based on Systemtime. I tried the following code but the callback function is never called

```
SYSTEMTIME st, lt;
GetSystemTime(&st); 

FILETIME ft;
SystemTimeToFileTime(&st, &ft);

ULONGLONG qwResult;

// Copy the time into a quadword.

qwResult = (((ULONGLONG) ft.dwHighDateTime) << 32) + ft.dwLowDateTime;

// Add 20 seconds days.
qwResult += 20 * _SECOND;


HANDLE hTimerQueue = CreateTimerQueue();
HANDLE hTimer;

// Set a timer to call the timer routine in 10 seconds.

if (!CreateTimerQueueTimer( &hTimer, hTimerQueue ,(WAITORTIMERCALLBACK)TimerAPCProc, NULL , qwResult, 0, 0))

{

 printf("CreateTimerQueueTimer failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());

 return 3;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The callback routine will be called in `qwResult` milliseconds, and file time gives you the time in 100 nanoseconds. You do the math. `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime` Will give you `FILETIME` right away if that is the path you want to go.

Personally, I would keep a list of structure with times when the routines should be called and pointers to routines and iterate through the list  once in a while and if the time of execution is due I would just call the function (or create a thread). That way your users can always review the scheduled tasks and change them.

Comment: I will have many such queues so i am not be able to afford a thread for each queue. The idea behind this approach i should be able to call a function when the time set by the user is due

Comment: Well you don't have to create a thread for each function but I don't think that scheduling a timer to run in about 12 hours is a good idea,
imho you should create one thread to constantly monitor the list of tasks and create something like a thread pool to execute task on limited number of threads, if no threads are available your task will have to wait

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be backed by `WaitForSingleObject`, or entering the thread into waitable state (using `SleepEx` for example).

Comment: i dont think so, because when i hard code the time to 10 the call back function is getting called. The problem is with the arithmetic or the way in which i convert the file time to unsigned long value

Comment: Please understand the difference between absolute time and relative time.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing in an absolute time, but the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) say you need to pass in the number of milliseconds from the current time.

If you want the timer to go off in 20 seconds, pass 20000 instead of `qwResult`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistakes. I have changed the code to invoke the timer based on relative time. But as SS Kain pointed out i may not be able to invoke the timer after 15 days or something like that because the difference in the milliseconds will be huge to be accommodated with DWORD

Comment: wow, 15 days is a problem?  You might want to consider reevaluating how you're approaching your scheduling.  You might want to schedule only the first few tasks, for example, and each time you process a task look at whats next in the queue.